# Handling of sex chromosomes in male when computing CNV copy ratio

Tags: microarray, copy-number, chromosomes, array-cgh

Reading from [CNVkit documentation](https://cnvkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sex.html#reference-sex-chromosome-ploidy), [Mathworks documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ug/detecting-dna-copy-number-alteration-in-array-based-cgh-data.html), [Bionano documentation](https://bionanogenomics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/30210-Introduction-to-Copy-Number-Analysis.pdf), for CNV calling, it seems that the common practice for array is to compute the linear copy ratio by normalizing against the expected depth for the reference ploidy, i.e.,:

$$CR = \frac{D_{OBS}}{P_{REF}}$$

where $D_{OBS}$ is the observed depth, and $P_{REF}$ is expected depth for the reference ploidy for a specific segment (i.e., expected depth for 2 copies for females, and males outside sex chromosomes or in PAR regions).

Is that correct? Are there alternative approaches used in array copy number calling?